# Add a staff generator capability

Tags: feature-request

This site is obviously about music. So I think that it would be a good idea to have some sort of staff generator. Instead of having to go out to the internet to try to find an example of what we are talking about, why not make an image generator? It could be inserted into the bar above the question box for styling. Something like

```
|undo|redo|add staff|
```

Then have a lightbox appear that shows a picture of a normal staff, then the options above it. So it would look like

```
_____________________________________________
|  |clef| |key sig| |time sig| |instrument|  |
|                                            |
|  *                                         |
|  *                                         |
|  *                                         |
|  *       [Generated image of staff]        |
|  *                                         |
|  *                                         |
|  *                                         |
_____________________________________________
```

The * is for different note lengths, such as quarter notes

This could be a drag and drop interface, or just a simple click on the staff

Of course, for more complicated runs that would take a long time to create with this feature (such as http://www.everynote.com/violin.show/3828.music), they could resort to the old method of finding a picture on the internet.

There is the possibility of downloading a software that would allow for making the staff that they are looking to make, but this can be a problem for some people. Not everyone has the money to buy a piece of software that will allow this, and there are people that don't have a lot of memory on their computer that don't want to have another application on their computer that they won't use very often. Also, not everyone has the time to learn the language needed to code a music staff. I don't believe there is any online staff generator. I know that for web design, there is jsfiddle.net, and so I was wondering if a low quality one could be made by the stack exchange team

Comment: As you can see we have discussed this sort of thing already ... I think we'd have to wait till the site is out of Beta to see anything.  I know also that the SE team needs it to be lightweight, and they are not likely to roll their own solution.

Comment: I still don't think this is a different question, the other does not preclude something direct from the SE team -- but again, I *highly* doubt that will happen.  It's not their area.